# How do I access an headless Linux connected to another Linux via USB in Ethernet Gadget mode?

Tags: routing, ethernet

This has been answered and solved in different ways throughout the internet, but my question is a bit more specific. My setting is as follows:

```
RPI_0 = Raspberry Pi Zero 2 W
RPI_4 = Raspberry Pi 4

RPI_0 <-usb cable-> RPI_4 <-- ssh --> Macbook
```

I connect using the MacBook to the RPI_4 and I can see on it that there is a new network interface, representing RPI_0 in Ethernet Gadget mode (enp1s0u1u1).

I did set up manually an IP address to enp1s0u1u1 of the like of 169.254.0.1 and tried to ssh into that address. SSH does answer, but I am unable to connect for whatever reason:

```
bidi@zero > ssh -l pi 169.254.0.1
pi@169.254.0.1's password: 
Permission denied, please try again.
pi@169.254.0.1's password:
```

And here is where I need your help. SSH does answer, but I cannot connect as I am welcomed with a Permission Denied.

I then enabled wifi on the RPI_0, and logged into the wifi interface IP address successfully. Once In, I noticed that the usb0, the gadget interface, has an IP address in the class 169.254.0.0/16, and that is to be expected.

Now my question is: how is it possible that I can reach ssh using my manually set IP address on the RPI_4, if on the other end of the cable usb0 on the RPI_4 has a different address?

Why do I get that Permission denied?

Should I be able to find the real address of the RPI_0 (from RPI_4) even if I set manually and arbitrarily an IP address for the enp1s0u1u1 interface of the RPI_4 using nmap?

```
nmap -sn 169.254.0.0/16
```

Comment: Welcome here, but sorry: I'm confused. How do you connect to the Pi4? Ethernet? With which IPs on both sides? Do you use the same IP range on both interfaces of Pi4 (this is likely to cause problems)? Please clarify your question.

Comment: Hi @Philippos. I connect the RPI4 using the ethernet cable, but the same could be done with wireless, I don't have issues in communication between my mac and RP4. The issue I have is between RPI_0 and RPI_4. The IP on both sides is different because I don't know which IP address RPI_0 has taken, but I do use the same range 169.25.0.0/16

Comment: If you use fixed IPs anyhow, the zeroconf range 169.254.0.0/16 is not preferred, I think. Use some 192.168.x.0/24 and check whether the problem does disappear.

Comment: Looks like you're connecting from the RPi4 to itself, on its own 169.254.0.1 address.

Comment: @A.B you were 100% right, sometimes my brain just farts. Thank you.